# Why if clicking button twice setInterval method is shorter then declared

Tags: javascript

I want to execute function FindNext() every second with setInterval method.
It works excellent if I click the button once, but if I click the button twice or more the interval starts to be shorter then declared - shorter then one second.I do not know how to make the time interval independent of button clicking number ?

```
<button id="search-next">Find - next</button>

$('#search-next').click(function() {
setInterval(function()  {
FindNext();
}, 1000);   
});
```

Comment: It\s not shorter. You simply have multiple timers running.

Answer (score 2):

It's not shorter. You simply have multiple timers running.
You could do something like this to check if there already is a timer running:

```
var myTimer = null;

$('#search-next').click(function() {
  if (myTimer === null) {
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
      FindNext();
    }, 1000);   
  }
});
```

or maybe use clearInterval before starting a new timer:

```
var myTimer = null;

$('#search-next').click(function() {
  if (myTimer !== null) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
  }

  myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    FindNext();
  }, 1000);   
});
```

Comment: Yes, @Sani Singh Huttunen and FeaturedSpace your answers are correct and my code is working excellent now.Only correction I made in first example is:                                             if (myTimer == null) {.....       .Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Becuase it's setting another interval. So now you have two loops. If you click one button 500 milliseconds after clicking another, it will start each at 500 milliseconds.

I suggest using `clearInterval(myIntervalVariable);`

You can do `var myIntervalVariable = setInterval(stuff);`